# iPhone XS crash on pthread_tsd_cleanup when spawning a C++ thread

Tags: c#, c++, ios, multithreading, unity-game-engine

We are getting a crash when spawning a thread using C++ using Unity on the latest iPhone XS devices. The crash only occurs on iPhone XS and iPhone XS Max not on older iPhones.

Below is the stack trace after the thread finishes executing

```
0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x000000022d4c7094 __abort + 188
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x000000022d4c6fd8 __abort + 0
2 libsystem_malloc.dylib 0x000000022d5c3c7c _malloc_put + 0
3 libsystem_malloc.dylib 0x000000022d5c3e48 malloc_report + 68
4 libsystem_malloc.dylib 0x000000022d5b5574 free + 412
5 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000022d5ed40c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 512
6 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000022d5e6cc8 _pthread_exit + 84
7 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000022d5e5a10 _pthread_body + 144
8 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000022d5e5960 _pthread_start + 52
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000022d5eddf4 thread_start + 4
```

Does anybody know if there have been any changes to the standard libraries on iOS 12 or specifically for iPhone XS?

We believe this to be a Unity related crash as it does not happen when:
1) You spawn a thread using standard pthreads
2) You spawn a thread using C++ on a standalone app without Unity

The crash occurs only when linking Unity and spawning a C++ thread

This is how we are running this test:

```
void *reproduce_crash()

{

pthread_setname_np("CrashingThread");

}


std::thread(reproduce_crash).detach()
```

I am linking to our open Unity boards thread as well as two sample apps (1 with Unity and 1 without that proves the issue, which once agains happens only on iPhone XS/XS Max)

https://forum.unity.com/threads/iphone-xs-crash-when-spawning-c-thread.574021/

https://ufile.io/e8m26

Below is a screenshot from running it with Address Sanitizer on:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Fixed by Unity on the latest version of Unity

Comment: From the stack itself it seems like free detects heap corruption after thread exits and than aborts. Is there output available?

Comment: Yes, will update the question with the image from running it with address sanitizer. As you can see the address that is over-freed is allocated by Unity it seems on IL2CPP.

Comment: Yep, it certainly seems so. Not sure if we on Stack Overflow can be of any help here, looks like the issue should be taken to Unity support.

Comment: It seems to be working on the latest alpha version of Unity 2019.1.0 Alpha 8.

Comment: Yup. they worked with us to fix it.